# Processing through multiple date parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

Within the select expert in crystal we need to show results from parameters within 4 different fields:

```
{@Award Date1}, {@Award Date2}, {@Award Date3}, {@Award Date4}.
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dRJ32ru.gif]

Is there something similar as a and/or formula which would show all results rather than restricting the parameter to one field.

```
{@Award Date1} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I don't think I explained exactly what I meant very well.

That is with the date parameters correctly showing everything in between them:
[image]

However, if wanted to display award dates between 15/02/2014 and 04/03/2014 then it should only display the two that are dated 20/02/2014, however this is not the case:

```
({@Award Date1} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}) OR 
({@Award Date2} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}) OR 
({@Award Date3} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}) OR 
({@Award Date4} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date})
```

Comment: Looks like the problem you're having stems from the fact that all 4 of the dates are _a single record_. Your record selection formula won't be able to tackle this problem.

Comment: Post the code of one of the formula fields (unless they are really different, then post all 4).

Comment: @EXPGDave I have edited my post try and let me know

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- create 4, new `details` sections
- move a pair of corresponding `{table.benefit_claimedX}` and `{@award dateX}` to each of the new `details` sections
- create a conditional-suppression formula for each `details` section that compares the `{@award dateX}` field to the parameter values (`NOT({@award date1} IN {?Start Date} TO {?End Date})`)
- mark the original `details` section as `underlay following sections`

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't seem to solve my problem. Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. I have updated the question with more information. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

{@Award Date1}>={?Start Date} and {@Award Date1}<={?End Date}

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

you are creating 4 formulas and displaying date... and you don't want to get the range of dates that you are not selected then you don't need to use the 4 formulas in select expert insead use like shown below.

```
<<Date database field>> in {?Start Date} to {?End Date}
```

This will retrive the required dates you selected in parameters and if your formula s (**{@Award Date1}, {@Award Date2}, {@Award Date3}, {@Award Date4}.
**)doesn't fit in these dates then those will be blank, of you wish you can supress aswell

Comment: This is just what OP wrote, but the _invalid syntax_ version. _Please_ check your code before posting!